# navigator has both navigation and container props error in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So Important : my project was working , bat when i copied them to my backup folder and used after deleting files!!, i got navigation error:

> Error: This navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is unclear if it should own its own state. Remove props: "theme" if the navigator should get its state from the navigation prop. If the navigator should maintain its own state, do not pass a navigation prop.

here is my App.js codes:

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation"
import AppNavigator from './app/Navi/Navigate'

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />
  }
}
```

Where i call AppNavigator from Navigate.js:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  indexPage : Index,
  loginPage : Login,
  homePage : TabNavigator
},
{
  initialRouteName: "indexPage",
  headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
        headerVisible: false,
    }
});

export default AppNavigator;
```

and index.js where error is there (error says it is in line 29 that refers to line 40) :

```
export default class Index extends React.Component{
 componentDidMount(){
        this.checker();
    }


    transfer = (page) => {
        if(page == 'Home')
            this.props.navigation.navigate('homePage');
        else
            this.props.navigation.navigate('loginPage');
    }

    checker = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('LoginBoolean')
        .then((value) => {
            if(value == 'yes')
                this.transfer('Home');
            else
                this.transfer('Login');
        })
        .catch((error) => 
            console.log(error)
        );
    }

    render(){
        some rendering tags!
    }
}
```

and no idea what is going on!

> Edited
>   the TabNavigator Compeletly Codes:

that const rednderNav and customTabs are some customization for tab ui

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Home from '../Home/home'
import LogOut from '../Logging/logout'
import Search from '../Route/Search'
import Poll from '../Poll/Poll'
import Signate from '../sign/signate'

const renderNav = (name, tintColor) => (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Icon name={name} size={15} style={{color: tintColor}} />
    </View>
  )

const customTabs = ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      if (routeName === 'LogOut') {
        return renderNav('md-log-out', tintColor);
      } else if (routeName === 'Home') {
        return renderNav('md-planet', tintColor);
      } else if (routeName === 'Route') {
        return renderNav('md-compass', tintColor);
      } else if (routeName === 'Poll') {
        return renderNav('ios-checkmark-circle', tintColor);
      } else if (routeName === 'Sign') {
        return renderNav('hand', tintColor);
      }
    }
  });

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    LogOut : LogOut,
    Route : Search,
    Home : Home,
    Poll : Poll,
    Sign : Signate
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: customTabs,
  animationEnabled: true,
  swipeEnabled: true,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  initialRouteName: 'Poll',
  tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,
    activeTintColor: 'yellow',
    inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
    style:{
      borderTopColor: '#ccc',
      borderTopWidth: 3,
      backgroundColor:'#191919',
      height: 50,
    },
    activeTabStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderBottomWidth: 40,
      borderColor: '#6C1D7C'
    }
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Comment: So for your case, what is the value of "LoginBoolean" ? And can we see what is inside TabNavigator?

Comment: i've added tabnavigator codes. and the LoginBoolean get these values: 'yes' and 'no' (actually not boolean!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, you are returning a AppContainer in your TabNavigator file, you should only have one AppContainer for all the application.

So the perfect way can be to return directly the Tabnavigator

```
export default TabNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved as follows

original:

```
export default createAppContainer( createBottomTabNavigator( {
```

modified:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator( {
```